# Unity APK doesn't open on One Plus 2 Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Im very new to programming and wanted to use unity and cardboard to create 3d walkthroughs. 
Now I managed to create an APK and transfer it to my phone but sadly when I open it the screen turns black for about 1 second and then Im back to menu. Ive installed the newest version of Unity and Android Studio.

Anyone got an idea what I can do to rectify this?

```
07-27 16:34:54.911 9917-9930/? E/Unity: Unable to find libaudioplugingvrunity
07-27 16:34:55.059 441-3879/? E/audio_hw_dolby: audio_extn_dolby_ds2_set_endpoint: Dolby set endpint :0x2
07-27 16:34:55.275 9917-9930/? E/VrApiLoader: Oculus updates needed.

                                              Instructions to receive new updates can be found at:

                                              https://support.oculus.com under 'Samsung Gear VR - Oculus Software Update'
07-27 16:34:55.276 9917-9930/? E/E:\tw\43ffd860e3c1b6c5\Software\OculusSDK\Integrations\Unity\Releases\si-1: VrApi initialization error.
07-27 16:34:55.276 9917-9930/? E/EntryPoints: vrapi_GetVersionString was called before vrapi_Initialize()!

                                              --------- beginning of crash
07-27 16:34:55.276 9917-9930/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9930 (UnityMain)
07-27 16:34:55.343 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-27 16:34:55.343 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus2/OnePlus2:6.0.1/MMB29M/1447840820:user/release-keys'
07-27 16:34:55.343 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
07-27 16:34:55.343 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
07-27 16:34:55.343 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG: pid: 9917, tid: 9930, name: UnityMain  >>> com.kpm.Test <<<
07-27 16:34:55.343 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
07-27 16:34:55.343 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 000026ca  r2 00000006  r3 f39bf978
07-27 16:34:55.343 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     r4 f39bf980  r5 f39bf930  r6 00000002  r7 0000010c
07-27 16:34:55.343 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     r8 f39bf55c  r9 ecda6300  sl f08b7c58  fp f39bd28c
07-27 16:34:55.343 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     ip 00000006  sp f39bd1e8  lr f703e145  pc f7040540  cpsr 400f0010
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00042540  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00040141  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0001c79f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00019941  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000174fc  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00003c04  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libvrapi.so
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000047ec  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libvrapi.so (vrapi_GetVersionString+16)
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00066fe0  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libOVRPlugin.so (SystemActivities_CreateSystemActivityIntent+136)
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00066cb0  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libOVRPlugin.so (SystemActivities_StartSystemActivity+160)
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0006788c  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libOVRPlugin.so (SystemActivities_DisplayError+984)
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00035c0c  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libOVRPlugin.so (_ZN3OVR4Util15CompositorVRAPI21SetupDistortionWindowEv+416)
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0002e788  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libOVRPlugin.so (ovrp_SetupDistortionWindow+72)
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 007a8418  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 007a7c4c  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 007a50b0  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 007a494c  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00389188  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 004d74cc  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 004dc710  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
07-27 16:34:55.349 9995-9995/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 0013bb11  /data/app/com.kpm.Test-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0xc8000)
07-27 16:34:55.732 1407-1478/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 68)
07-27 16:34:55.735 1407-4059/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '6f6d2cd com.kpm.Test/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-27 16:34:55.740 435-1180/? E/FrameworkListener: read() failed (Connection reset by peer)
07-27 16:34:56.804 1689-10020/? E/GmsUtils: Failed to connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
07-27 16:36:48.535 10065-10085/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: mmsconfig
07-27 16:36:48.539 10065-10085/? E/Babel_SMS: canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc nullnull
07-27 16:36:55.808 489-4132/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: wait_wake_up  -4  2
07-27 16:36:55.808 489-4132/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: fpc_wait_finger_down_for_home  -4  2
07-27 16:36:55.808 489-4132/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: do_home  -4  00
07-27 16:36:55.808 489-4132/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: do_identify
07-27 16:36:55.860 489-4132/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: do_identify status 0
07-27 16:36:55.860 489-4132/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: fpc_capture_image
07-27 16:36:55.860 489-4132/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: fpc_wait_finger_up
07-27 16:36:56.017 489-4132/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: fpc_wait_finger_up FPC_LIB_FINGER_LOST
07-27 16:36:56.017 489-4132/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: fpc_wait_finger_down enter ---
07-27 16:36:56.017 489-4132/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: wait_wake_up  0    1
07-27 16:36:56.120 489-4131/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: screenStateFunction screen OFF 0 
07-27 16:36:56.374 9489-9494/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Warning: Core control support not present for lock_min_cores on cluster 0 for this target
07-27 16:36:56.374 9489-9494/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [4, 0]
07-27 16:36:56.422 441-9884/? E/bt_a2dp_hw: adev_set_parameters: ERROR: set param called even when stream out is null
07-27 16:36:56.423 1407-4068/? E/native: do suspend true
```

Comment: what were your build settings and what settings did you use for the cardboard main ?

Comment: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/239

Comment: thanks but that did really help me im afraid. I tried turning off the audio scripts+components. I tried deleting those but nothing helped.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Pgwz21vX is the new error code im getting

Comment: You seem to keep getting a error for OcculusSDK and your should be using just GoogleVR SDK for unity. Do you have the two sdk in the same project? because otherwise it's really strange for it to ask for Occulus updates.

Comment: I used the sdk that was given [here](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/download) so I recon that should be correct. But maybe its in the code I used for the auto walk? The code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/uMcw6bnp)

Answer (score 0):

When building the scene for Android you have to change the Player Settings. Uncheck "VR Supported" under the "Other Settings tab" there.